# Getting an alert when my oracle database goes up or down

Tags: email, oracle, network-monitoring, monitoring

How can I get an e-mail alert when my oracle database comes up or down?

I have a database that I need to know when it goes down (it would be nice to know if it has come back up), preferably from a remote machine. Conceivably I could hack together something that TNSPings my DB and e-mails me when that changes, but I'm hoping there's a free package out there. Something that would run on windows.

Any strong recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a http://www.bigsister.ch/bigsister.html

I 've used this in the past to monitor a small network. You can also add checks to test, if services (e.g. Oracle Listener) are available.

Comment: Excellent, it's free and it works on windows. I'll see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use Nagios, it's free and have Oracle connectors

http://www.nagios.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [system triggers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/triggers.htm#i6061) to do some of this. You could combine the trigger with the use of the [UTL_MAIL package](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_mail.htm). You might be able to use dbms_scheduler if you're monitoring via another database.

Additional info: I found [DBUptime](http://www.dkgas.com/dbuptime.htm) on [Burleson's Guide to free Oracle Utilities Page](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2005_3_16_guide_free_utilities.htm). Maybe that's more what you want.

Comment: close... triggers would not be remote, and the other solution not really free (free to try though).

Comment: Sorry, $39 is as close to free as I can find :-|